# Video isn't showing on my webpage

Tags: html, css, video

I've recorded a video which lasts 3:48 minutes and I have implemented it into my webpage, while I have the navigation bar and the sound, my video doesn't seem to show anything? It looks just like that:

[image]

Here is my *HTML*:

```
<video height="90%" width="90%" class="demoVideo" controls><source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

and *CSS*:

```
.demoVideo {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 20;
    background-color: transparent;
    max-width: 77.083333333333%;
    max-height: 77.12962962963%;
    margin-left: 11.458333333333%;
    top: 11.111111111111%;
    border: 1px white solid;
}
```

Here is my Video Codec info:

[image]

Comment: Please show us what error is displayed.

Comment: @eronax59 No error is being displayed, the video just doesn't show, but still has sound

Comment: use this video link temporary http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4 and check what comes.

Comment: <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you verify what video codec has been used to record your .mp4 file?

Most of the latest major browsers natively support the MP4 container format with the H.264 video codec and the AAC audio codec.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

You can open your video file using VLC Media Player. Then go to Window > Media Information and click on Codec details to see what video and sound codec was used.

Comment: It looks like your video hasn't been recorded in H.264 format but with MPEG-4 Video. Try adding the "codec" information in the Type attribute. For example, <source src='video.mp4' type='video/mp4; codecs="mp4v.20.8, mp4a.40.2"'>. 

If the "mp4v.20.8" is incorrect try using a different one as shown in the link below. 
https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-source-element.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the same failure. I converted the original avi file to webm instead of mp4 and it worked. This saved me learning anything about codecs etc. It's a blunt instrument but it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
<video height="500" width="500" class="demoVideo" controls>
<source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

and CSS:

```
.demoVideo {
position: fixed;
z-index: 20;
background-color: transparent;
min-width: 75%;
min-height: 75%;
margin-left: 10%;
top: 10%;
border: 1px white solid;
}
```

Reference:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: "Your browser does not support the video tag." Are you gettting this ?